# Make letterhead print on only the first page in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a letterhead document created for me. When inserting info into the document I would like the letterhead to show on the first page, only! Now it shows up on all subsequent pages, also.

Answer (score 3):

> **Letterhead printing on all pages**
>
> When inserting info into the document I would like the letterhead to
>   show on the first page only!

### Embedded Approach

You could also just have the header information at the top of the first page as part of the page content.  If it's already been created as a header, you can cut and paste into the body of the page.  If you are creating the document or template from scratch, you could simply enter the content on page one and format it using the standard Word options, features, and functions rather than use the Header options.

Letterheads are often positioned outside the margins of the normal page.  If you enter them as part of the page body, you may need to adjust things like margins on the first page and then add a section break and change those settings back before the second page.  A simpler approach in this situation is to embed the letterhead components as objects, like an image or text box. This lets you position them wherever you want without affecting the page layout.

Insert it at the top of the first page and resize, move, or format it to emulate a header, positioned where you want it. For example, in the below screenshot (and moving GIF), I inserted a text box, pasted a picture into that, positioned it where I wanted it to be located, hid the outline, etc. and then put the other text and long appended underbar and formated all the colors how I wanted those parts.

With a little trial and error, finding these and other built in Microsoft Office Word features and functions with the version of Word on your PC, you could build your own custom header at the top of the first page this way too.

[image]

### Moving Images Showing Quick Steps

**Windows Word 2007/Word 2010** 
[image]

**Windows Word 2013**
[image]

Comment: Glad I checked back.  The "@" addressing only works for users who have already participated in that specific post (the full, convoluted explanation is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)).  Anyway, two well done answers that pretty much cover the options.  Hopefully, the OP will return, recognize the work that went into these, and [accept](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) one.

Answer (score 2):

> **Letterhead printing on all pages**
>
> When inserting info into the document I would like the letterhead to
>   show on the first page only!

Below are the steps to follow to complete this task but you didn't state which version of Microsoft Word you are using. The below steps will work for Office Word 2007, 2010, and 2013.

**NOTE:** If you're using Word Online then please see here for [**Word Online**](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Put-a-header-only-on-the-first-page-0041ED9C-E5A3-4A29-9501-D45A24C8F835) instructions for completing this task.

> ### [For Windows Word 2007/Word 2010](https://support.apu.edu/entries/38767028-Creating-a-Microsoft-Word-Header-Footer-for-the-first-page-only)
>
> Go to **Insert** on the Ribbon, click on the **Header** icon and then select
>   **Edit Header**

[image: Screen_Shot_2014-01-21_at_2.10.38_PM.png]

> Locate the "*Design*" located under the title "**Header & Footer Tools**"
>   Check the box "**Different First Page**"

[image: Screen_Shot_2014-01-21_at_2.15.06_PM.png]

> You will then see the new "**Header**" area:

After this point with these options selected put in what you need in
   your top page header area only (insert pics type tesxt, etc.) that
   you want to only show on the first page. Be sure you do not put
   anything in the header area of the first or topmost page header area
   unless the **"Different First Page"** option is select.

---

> ### For Windows Word 2013
>
> Go to **Insert** on the Ribbon, click on the **Header** icon and then
>   select **Edit Header**

[image]

> Locate the "*Design*" located under the title "**Header & Footer Tools**"
>   Check the box "**Different First Page**"

[image]

> You will then see the new "**Header**" area:

After this point with these options selected put in what you need in
   your top page header area only (insert pics type tesxt, etc.) that
   you want to only show on the first page. Be sure you do not put
   anything in the header area of the first or topmost page header area
   unless the **"Different First Page"** option is select.

---